# Error when installing the ADT plugins in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 and when I followed the steps on this tutorial(http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html). I got an error message during the last steps.

> An error occurred while installing the
>   items   session context
>   was:(profile=PlatformProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Install,
>   operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.cvs
>   1.0.400.v201002111343, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
>   The artifact file for
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.0.400.v201002111343
>   was not found.was not found.

would be grateful if anyone can help me out :)

Thanks.

P.S. I'm running Ubuntu Lucid Lynx with kernel 2.6.32-24-generic on x86_64. I have the ia32libs installed as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you install Eclipse from the Ubuntu Software Center ? Apparently there are several packages missing from that install.

You should be able to fix it with an `sudo apt-get install eclipse-plugin-cvs eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde`

Comment: Yes, installing eclipse-pde resolved the issue. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad it got it sorted for you :) I guess in hindsight it would be that one as that's the plugin development package.